# Where can I find a list of safe Windows Updates

Tags: windows, updates

I am installing a Windows Server Update Services server but I can't see where you can find out if a particular update is safe or not. I am trying to avoid installing updates that will break our servers/PCs.

Comment: no  such thing. the safety of an update is directly related to your exact services and their configuration.

Comment: You should install ALL security updates. You should also test every update released to verify there will not be compatability problems with your configuration before you push the update to your users.  In other words you should generate the list yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this will depend on your installed applications / services - I've not encountered a canonical listing of universally safe patches.

For a month by month approach (and I suspect older months will have been archived), I quite like [Randy Smith's Patch listings](http://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/Default.aspx), which generally gives you an idea of what will need to be restarted, what it will affect, and if you should install it immediately or test it first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such things as 'Safe Windows updates'. Where in the past individual updates gave errors for (groups of) individual users, Microsoft patched these. All the critical updates they supply are considered safe until proven otherwise (which rarely happens).